# Why does this proof claim that $z$ is both the sum and the difference of the same terms?

Tags: complex-numbers

The following is the proof from a textbook for why $z+\frac{1}{z} = 2\cos\theta$, where $z$ is a complex number.

> Suppose $z= \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$, then
>
> $z^{-1}=\frac{1}{z}=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^{-1}$
>
> $=\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta) $
>
> $=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$            $(=z)$ [1]
>
> So $z=\cos\theta + i\sin \theta$
>
> $\frac{1}{z}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$
>
> Adding, $z+\frac{1}{z} = 2\cos\theta$

Could someone please explain why [1] is the case, i.e. why $\cos\theta-i\sin\theta =z$, because this is not the same as the z defined at the start of the proof. I believe this could be a potential case of a typo.

Comment: I think the intended remark was $z^{-1}=\bar{z}$, the conjugate of $z$. So a typo in which the bar was missing.

Comment: It seems really a typo. It must be $=z^{-1}$ or $\bar z$, and really $z+z^{-1}=2\cos \theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely it's a typo.

$ z = a + ib \\
z \cdot z^{-1} = 1 \\
\Rightarrow z^{-1} = 1/z = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2} - i \cdot \frac{b}{a^2+b^2}
$

Now, let's apply this to $ z=\cos\theta + i \cdot \sin\theta $;

$a = \sin\theta \\
b = \cos\theta \\
a^2+b^2 = 1\\
z^{-1} = \cos\theta - i \cdot \sin\theta$

Finally;

$ z + z^{-1} = (\cos\theta + i \cdot \sin\theta) + (\cos\theta - i \cdot \sin\theta) = 2\cos\theta$.

Result: It's a typo.